# std::set_Differences Not working with read files

Tags: c++

I have a strange issue with the set_differences function from the `<algorithm>` header. I am attempting to read two text files line by line and each line is put into a corresponding set. For some reason set-difference does not detect any difference between the two sets though there most certainly are. When I hardcode populate two sets it works just fine. It must be something with the content of the strings read from the files but I can't figure out what.

```
#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>    
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

std::set<std::string> listOfFiles(std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream tempFile;
    tempFile.open(fileName.c_str());
    std::string X;
    std::set<std::string> fileNameSet;
    if (tempFile.is_open()) {
        while (std::getline(tempFile, X)) {
            fileNameSet.insert(X);
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open " + fileName + "\n";
        exit(0);
    }
    return fileNameSet;
}
std::set<std::string> setDifferences(std::set<std::string> a, std::set<std::string> b) {
    using namespace std;
    set<string> result;
    set_difference( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), inserter(result, result.begin()));
    cout << "Difference" << endl << "-------------" << endl;
    for (set<string>::const_iterator i = result.begin(); i != result.end(); ++i) {
        cout << *i << endl;
    } 
    return result;
}
int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> initialSet = listOfFiles("test1.txt");
    std::set<std::string> afterNGD = listOfFiles("test2.txt");
    std::set<std::string> result, result2;
    std::set<std::string> a, b;
    a.insert("one");
    a.insert("two");
    a.insert("three");
    b.insert("a");
    b.insert("b");
    b.insert("three");

    //Fails: result is empty
    result = setDifferences(initialSet, afterNGD);


    //Pass: result2 constains strings "one" and "two"
    result2 = setDifferences(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

My text files contain:
test1.txt

```
.Xil
fileNames.txt
hostlistfile.txt
ipcore_dir
iseconfig
item.prj
item.sch
item.sym
item.syr
item.ucf
item.vhf
item.xdl
item.xst
item_bitgen.xwbt
item_guide.ncd
item_summary.html
pa.fromNcd.tcl
planAhead.ngc2edif.log
planAhead_pid11956.debug
planAhead_pid1272.debug
planAhead_pid16492.debug
planAhead_pid19040.debug
planAhead_pid7804.debug
planAhead_pid9888.debug
planAhead_run_1
planAhead_run_2
sch2HdlBatchFile
SingleItemTest.gise
SingleItemTest.tcl
SingleItemTest.xise
template files
templates
xst
_xmsgs
```

text2.txt:

```
.Xil
fileNames.txt
hostlistfile.txt
ipcore_dir
iseconfig
item.bld
item.lso
item.ngc
item.ngd
item.ngr
item.prj
item.sch
item.sym
item.syr
item.ucf
item.vhf
item.xdl
item.xst
item_bitgen.xwbt
item_guide.ncd
item_ngdbuild.xrpt
item_summary.html
item_vhdl.prj
item_xst.xrpt
pa.fromNcd.tcl
planAhead.ngc2edif.log
planAhead_pid11956.debug
planAhead_pid1272.debug
planAhead_pid16492.debug
planAhead_pid19040.debug
planAhead_pid7804.debug
planAhead_pid9888.debug
planAhead_run_1
planAhead_run_2
sch2HdlBatchFile
SingleItemTest.gise
SingleItemTest.tcl
SingleItemTest.xise
template files
templates
xlnx_auto_0_xdb
xst
_ngo
_xmsgs
```

Comment: Do you check the content of `initialSet` is right after finishing reading the file?

Comment: A [mcve] would be really handy, with the emphasis on minimal. What's the smallest set of data in the two files that causes this issue? Get rid of the I/O code and initialize the sets with this minimal data directly. If you cannot minimize the program and still have `set_difference` fail, then it cannot be the problem and you should minimize in a different direction.

Answer (score 1):

From the [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference):

> Copies the elements from the sorted range [first1, last1) **which are
>   not found** in the sorted range [first2, last2) to the range beginning
>   at d_first.

From your example files, all the elements in `text1.txt` *can be found* in `text2.txt`, so the output is as expected.